# shade smooth, shade flat

Tags: shaders

in older blender you pressed T and a menu on the left popped out with a lot of options, there was also

-shade smooth/flat in the list

where did that menu go? by looing at the blender manual it simply tells me

''object mode > object > shade smooth''

and then shows examples of how it works but gives no instructions on where to actually find this option, pretty much the entire blender manual looks like that with most things to be honest (is there any other version of a manual for blender, with more visual aid?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no other manual I'm aware of. It's talking about the menus at the top, on the editor header:

[image]

You can also simply right click on the object:

[image]